# CoreML: why is the predictions an array?

Tags: swift, macos, coreml, createml

consider a `csv` file like this:

```
number,weigth,length,depth,diameter
1,100,202,314,455
2,1040,2062,3314,4585
3,1200,2502,3134,4557
4,1500,2052,3143,4655
...
```

and a code like this

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myData", withExtension: "csv")!
let  dataTable = try! MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)
```

//    print(dataTable)

```
let regressorColumns = ["weigth", "length", "depth", "diameter"]
let regressorTable = dataTable[regressorColumns]

let (regressorEvaluationTable, regressorTrainingTable) = regressorTable.randomSplit(by: 0.20, seed: 5)

let regressor = try! MLLinearRegressor(trainingData: regressorTrainingTable,
                                      targetColumn: "weigth")

let prediction = try! regressor.predictions(from: dataTable)
print (prediction)
```

`prediction` is an array of floats with the same number of elements of the `csv` file itself.

Four questions:

1. why is it an array?
2. why floats?
3. why the array has the same number of elements as the input `csv`?
4. what exactly this array represents?

Comment: sorry, that was me checking the number of items on it. I should not copy it here. I have fixed the code.

Comment: Isn't the main goal of linear regression to draw a line that fits your data? What would you expect `prediction` to be?

Comment: It’s not actually an array, but homogeneous collection of data values, similar to an array (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/mluntypedcolumn))

Comment: what does this data mean?

Comment: I'm far from an expert in the field, but in your example, I would expect the predictions to be a "weigth" (sic) value for each row (by a model trained using 3 features: length, depth & diameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the code you posted does is it trains a machine learning model (specifically – a linear regression model) on some input data (`regressorTrainingTable`) with the goal to be able to predict some weight value (a "dependent" or "target" value) based on length, depth and diameter ("independent" or "feature" values).
Then this model is actually used to calculate a weight value for every row of data (length, depth and diameter) stored in `dataTable`.

So `prediction` is a collection of predictions of what a weight value would be based on the values of length, depth and diameter for each row stored in `dataTable`. Hopefully this answers question 1, 3 and 4.

As for the second question, it just has to do with how linear regression approach to building a model works under the hood. When building (training) a model, it treats all input (both dependent and independent) values as continuous numeric (that is, floats) even if they are expressed as integers in a datafile.